Poller to send messages out to kafka binding
The code below using spring cloud stream kafka works fine but everything has to be in this one method.
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, "--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.outbound-out-0.destination=out-topic");
    }
    @Bean
    Supplier<String> outbound() {
        return () -> {
            return LocalTime.now().toString();
        };
    }
}

How can I write an IntegrationFlow to do the same thing and use the outbound binder and allow me to add transformers, etc? The code below throws error: MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
Application class:
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.Pollers;
import java.time.LocalTime;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, "--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.outbound-out-0.destination=out-topic");
    }
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.fromSupplier(this::myPoller, p -> p.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
                .transform(m -> {
                    System.out.println("my transformer");
                    return m;
                })
                .channel("outbound")
                .get();
    }

    String myPoller() {
            return LocalTime.now() + " value";
    }
}

Gradle config:
build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.9'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2023.0.3")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-binder'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


From the doc, https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/channel/configuration.html#channel-configuration-pubsubchannel

Starting with version 5.4.3, the PublishSubscribeChannel can also be
configured with the requireSubscribers option of its
BroadcastingDispatcher to indicate that this channel will not ignore a
message silently when it has no subscribers. A
MessageDispatchingException with a Dispatcher has no subscribers
message is thrown when there are no subscribers and this option is set
to true.

the code
.channel("outbound")

populate a MessageChannelReference instance at the current IntegrationFlow chain position. The provided messageChannelName (here is 'outbound') is used for the bean registration (DirectChannel), if there is no such a bean in the application context. Otherwise, the existing MessageChannel bean is used to wire integration endpoints.
So the exception is just the default if there are no subscribers of this MessageChannel instance.
Add a subscriber, then the exception will disappear.
    // this will bring this channel out, then it can be referred below.
    @Bean("outbound")
    public DirectChannel outboundChannel() {
        DirectChannel directChannel = new DirectChannel();
        return directChannel;
    }
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow kafkaConsumerFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("outbound")
                .handle(this::handleMessage)  // Delegate to the method
                .get();
    }

    private void handleMessage(Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message.getPayload());
    }


Yes, the exception disappeared and messages are flowing to the channel, but they're not passed to outbound-out-0 kafka binding and are not going to kafka topic

@mike27 Yes, if you want to send data to kafka topic, you need to use kafkaTemplate as the message handler link,  or you can use spring cloud stream to declare kafka bindings.
link

That's the issue, I declared spring binding spring.cloud.stream.bindings.outbound-out-0.destination=out-topic and I don't understand how I can send a message from integration flow to this binding

In order to build an IntegrationFlow which sends messages to a Kafka topic using Spring Cloud Stream, the programmer that is you need to properly configure the flow to connect with the output channel and use proper binder.
I found that the problem in your code is that the channel (outbound) does not bind with the Kafka binder automatically. Thus, you should use the MessageChannel provided by Spring Cloud Stream.
Here the below given code is the corrected one:-

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
    import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
    import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
    import org.springframework.integration.dsl.Pollers;
    
    import java.time.LocalTime;
    
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, "--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.outbound-out-0.destination=out-topic");
        }
    
        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlows.fromSupplier(this::myPoller,
                            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
                    .transform(m -> {
                        System.out.println("my transformer: " + m);
                        return m;
                    })
                    .channel(Source.OUTPUT)
                    .get();
        }
    
        String myPoller() {
            return LocalTime.now() + " value";
        }
    }


I hope this code has resolved your query.

I use Spring cloud stream 4.1.3. There's no Source class. I can't find equivalent. Do you know what it is?

Ok, then instead of using Source.OUTPUT try to configure the channel name directly in you application.yml or application.properties and then use the channel name in the .channel().

@mike27 , In case if you find any difficulties then let me know I will give a fresh answer.

Sorry, not sure how to define a channel in properties?

It would be better for me to understand your pre written code more better once you will provide the complete codes such as the dependencies, file path etc.
So, I will suggest you to edit your question and provide the code and dependents in detail.

I edit the code
